# Installing git+svn on Mac OS Lion (issue with db46)

Tags: git, svn, installation, macports

I have installed MacPorts v2.0.3 on Mac OS Lion and trying to install git+svn via command

> sudo port instal git-core +svn

installation process aborts on building 'db46'

Any solution?

Ling to build log file: [it was deleted]

Comment: Without the specific error you're getting, the only answers that can be made to this question are speculations.

Comment: I finally done it by installing db46 separately from git-core installation process.

Comment: @esmimov did you have any particular command line parameters to port to make installing db46 separately work?  I'm also having this issue, although simply "sudo port install db46" does not work, and gives the same errors in log as yours, above.

Comment: @levis501 I've just used "sudo port install db46"

Comment: Thanks.  I had to reinstall xcode, which fixed it for me.